# MSP430 CMP operator

Tags: assembly, msp430

Let's say I have the MSP430 assembly segment below:

r15:

```
439c
```

Memory map:

```
4390:   6045 0200 9c43 6400 8844 5044 363a 0000
```

Code:

```
448a:  cmp  #0x363a, 0x0(r15)
4490:  jnz  $+0x1c
4492:  Code continues
.
.
.
44ac: Jump to location
```

The goal is to have the Z flag high. To do this with a cmp, both src and dst must be equal.
If I have 363a in the memory location of r15, why is it that the resulting cmp does not trigger the Z flag?

Through experimentation, I found that putting 3a36 in the memory location of r15 did in fact trigger the Z flag, but I don't understand why.

If anyone could bring this to light, I would greatly appreciate it.

If more information is needed, I will gladly provide it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason is that the [MSP430](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI_MSP430#MSP430_CPU) is a **little endian** machine.
I.e. the byte at the lower addres `0x439C` is interpreted as the **Least** Significant Byte.
The byte at the higher address `0x439D` is interpreted as the **Most** Significant Byte.
So the 16-bit value in memory actually is interpreted as `0x36 + (0x3A << 8) = 0x3A36`.

This explains also why you get Z flag set if you swap both bytes.

Note:
 
In memory dumps bytes are listed from left to right from lower to higher addresses.
Only for big endian machines (e.g. MC680x0) you can interpret multi byte values as they are listed in the memory dump; 
for little endian machines (e.g. x86, MSP430) you have to reverse the order of bytes of multi byte values to interpet them correctly.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, it makes sense. My confusion was with big and little endian. I assumed that they were bit wise reversals and not byte wise.